# How to query SQL Statements for all cubes out of Microstrategy back end

Tags: mysql, microstrategy

I've inherited a Microstrategy instance with several hundred cubes / reports on it.  I'd like to query out (in bulk) the SQL statements that underlie all of the cubes so that I can do some subsequent parsing / analysis (with Python) on those SQL statements and understand which databases and tables are most used in upstream data sources.

I have administrative access to the backend database but am not sure which table(s) I should look at to accomplish my goal. My guess is that they're in the `mstr_stat_live`  database, but I can't say for sure.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to generate a dataset with these fields:
`Cube ID`, `Cube Name`, `Cube Database Connection`, `Cube SQL Statement`

Which tables should I look at to glean this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can get full list of objects of specific object type with search API.
And also you can get a sql view of reports.

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/RESTSDK/Content/retrieve_sql_report_card.htm